# Android: How to get app usage activity below API level 21?

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app that shows user his time spent on various apps. Since their is a library available for this namely: '[android.app.usage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html)' But this package is available at API level 21. Since I don't want to lose 22% market share, is there any other way available to programmatically get app usage activity below API level 21?

Comment: Read that - `NOTE: This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Firebase Analytics** for that. Firebase has a user property called `OS Version` which will let you know about the usage on particular api level. Also you can send the data to BigQuery for detailed insights.